# Rad Studio 10 Seattle - XMLTransformProvider - Encoding UTF-8

Tags: delphi, xml, codificação-de-caracteres, delphi-10

Possuo 2 aplicações desenvolvidas no RAD XE2. Uma tem como objeto a digitação de dados que serão gravados em um arquivo XML e a outra, responsável por ler, validar e importar o XML gerado para o Banco de Dados.

Resolvi testar o *Rad 10 Seatle* e recompilei as aplicações. Quase tudo funciona, mas na hora de importar os dados a versão compilada no Delphi-10 não reconhece o encoding (UTF-8).
Se eu exportar pela versão do Delphi-10 e importar pela versão compilada no XE2 funciona normalmente.

Para importa e gerar o arquivo XML eu utilizei o XML Mapper para criar um arquivo de configuração (xtr). Quando testo a importação dos dados do XML dentro do XML Mapper, ele me exibe os carcteres corretamente (ã, ç, etc).
Para importação de dados utilizo um XMLTransformProvider ("ligado"  ao arquivo de configuração xtr) , e o XMLTransformProvider  é "ligado" a um clientdataset onde os dados são carregados. Acho que é neste ponto que o problema ocorre, pois quando visualizo os dados do clientdataset, eles aparecem incorretos (os carates especiais não são reconhecidos).

Se alguém puder dar uma dica, fico grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente esta alternativa:

Crie um evento privado chamado OnGetText conforme abaixo e no evento AfterOpen do ClientDataSet atribua a rotina abaixo.

```
Procedure TForm1.OnGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: String; DisplayText: Boolean);
Begin
    text:=Utf8ToString(sender.asString);
End;

procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
    i:integer;
    f:TField;
begin
    for i:=0 to dataset.fields.count-1 do
    begin
        f:=dataset.fields[i];
        f.ongettext:= Self.OnGetText;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Olá Carlos,
Obrigado pela ajuda. A sobreposição do método OnGetText não funcionou, porém a conversão com Utf8ToString funciona. Por enquanto estou utilizando o código que vc colocou no AfterOpen para corrigir "na mão" após a abertura da tabela até descobrir como sobrepor o OnGetText corretamente.